# Is it dangerous to rely on overflow?

Tags: c++, c, timer, delay, counter

The following is a delay function I found in our firmware.  It looks a little dangerous or, at the least, confusing to the reader.

**Global Variable**

```
static int32u masterTimerCounter; // 32-bit unsigned timer counter
```

**System Tick Interrupt Handler**

```
/* Called Every Millisecond */
void sysTickIrqHandler(void)
{
    masterTimerCounter++;
}
```

**Set Timer Expiration Function**

```
void setTimerExpiration(int32u *timerExpiration, int32u delay)
{
    *timerExpiration = masterTimerCounter + delay;
}
```

**Check If Timer Expired Function**

```
boolean timerExpired(int32u timerExpiration, int32u delay)
{
    if((masterTimerCounter - timerExpiration) < delay)
        return TRUE; // Timer has expired
    else
        return FALSE; // Timer still active
}
```

**Set Timer Expriation And Block Until Timer Expired**

```
int32u timerExpiration;
setTimerExpiration(&timerExpiration, 15); // Set expiration timer to 15 milliseconds
while(!timerExpired(timerExpiration, 15) // Block until timer has expired
    continue;
```

**Question**

As you can see in `timerExpired()`, `masterTimerCounter` is subtracted by `timerExpiration`.  If the timer hasn't expired yet, the computation will result in a very large number (because both of the operands are unsigned numbers).  When the timer has expired the computation will result in a value less than the delay amount.

Though this seems to work fine, it seems like it can be dangerous or, at the least, be confusing to the reader (I had to read it several times to understand the original programmer's intent).

If I had to write something similar to this, I would define the `timerExpired` function as follows:

```
boolean timerExpired(int32u timerExpiration)
{
    if(timerExpiration > masterTimerCounter)
        return FALSE; // Timer still active
    else
        return TRUE; // Timer has expired
}
```

Should I redefine 'timerExpired()`?

*Note: Function and variable names have been changed to protect the innocent.*

Comment: Are you ok with ignoring `delay` then?

Comment: `timerExpired` with the delay as parameter doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: `delay` really isn't needed any more if I redefine `timerExpired()`.

Comment: You, actually, removed *delay* parameter. But nothing proves that it is useless from the code provided.

Comment: @SChepurin With my redefinition, it is no longer relying on a smaller `unsigned` number being subtracted by a larger `unsigned` number resulting in a huge `unsigned` number (a number greater than `delay`.

Comment: You're assuming `timerExpiration` is _always_ in the future, which is unlikely to be the case. When the LHS _doesn't_ underflow, your behaviour is still different.

Comment: Changing the functionality (by removing the delay calculation) is not a refactoring.

Comment: What is the `sizeof(int)`?  IOW, what prevents `sysTickIrqHandler()` from altering the `int32u masterTimerCounter` in the middle of a `if((masterTimerCounter - timerExpiration) < delay)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your way is that if `masterTimerCounter + delay` causes a rollover of the 32 bit int, than the `timerExpired` test passes right away.

I think the most straightforward way to do integer timers in the presence of possible rollover is like this:

```
void startTimer(int32u *timerValue)
{
    *timerValue = masterTimerCounter;
}
```

Check If Timer Expired Function

```
boolean timerExpired(int32u timerVal, int32u delay)
{
    if ((masterTimerCounter - timerVal) >= delay)
        return TRUE; // Timer has expired
    else
        return FALSE; // Timer still active
}
```

Usage:

```
int32u timer;
startTimer(&timer); // Start timing
while(!timerExpired(timer, 15) // Block for 15 ticks
    continue;
```

Even if the subtraction in `timerExpired` underflows this returns the correct results.

Comment: Having the unsigned int rollover is not my way, it is the way it is now.  My question is, is this dangerous and if so, should I change it.    The way I was thinking I should change it is on the bottom of my question.

Comment: Imagine that masterTimer is 2^16-10 and you call it with a delay of 15.  Can you guarantee your system won't run for that many milliseconds continuously?

Comment: `masterTimerCounter` is actually a 32-bit unsigned number.  It runs in the bootloader only.  After the bootloader is finished the application is started. `masterTimerCounter == 0xFFFFFFFF == 4294967295 ms == 49.7 days`

Comment: Ok, so 49.7 days is a bit long for a bootloader.  (The last time I did something like this it was with 16 bit timers).  Still, the original code is safe in the presence of timer rollover, while your suggestion is not.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the original logic was something like: *is the absolute expiry time in the past, but less than a full delay period ago*. Maybe we could express it loosely as *did this timer fire recently*.

Your modified logic is just *is the absolute expiry time in the past*, which is different.

---

You can trivially avoid the risk of underflow by simply adding `timerExpiration` to each side of the inequality:

```
boolean timerExpired(int32u timerExpiration, int32u delay)
{
// WAS: (masterTimerCounter - timerExpiration) < delay
    if(masterTimerCounter < timerExpiration + delay)
        return TRUE; // Timer has expired
    else
        return FALSE; // Timer still active
}
```

but this changes the behaviour, since you say the original will always be false if `masterTimerCounter < timerExpiration`. You can get the original behaviour without the confusing underflow by checking this explicitly:

```
boolean timerExpired(int32u timerExpiration, int32u delay)
{
    if(masterTimerCounter > timerExpiration &&       // did it expire ...
       masterTimerCounter < timerExpiration + delay) // ... recently?
        return TRUE; // Timer has expired
    else
        return FALSE; // Timer still active
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That firmware code makes no sense.

```
int32u expire;
setTimerExpiration(&expire, 0);
timerExpired(expire, 0); // is always false, unless the timer overflows
```

Comment: It can never be true with delay 0, but it can be true with delay 15 as in the question